# Inserting rows with multiple columns into BigQuery using Avro

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I have problems creating a simple table using Avro as import format. I would like to create a typical table with N columns of primitive data types, for example a table with columns `c1 STRING` and `c2 INTEGER`.

I use schema like this

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "x",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "c1",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "c2",
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

This results into one column with name `root` of type `RECORD` having nested `c1` and `c2`.

How can import to a table that has two columns `c1` and `c2` with Avro? Or is it currently possible to only create tables with one column with fixed name `root`?

I tried other approaches:

- Avro type `array` (of `string`) creates one columns with name `root` of type `STRING REPEATED`
- Simplest schema like `{"type":"string"}` creates one column with name `root` of type `STRING`. This approach doesn't let create more than one column nor change the name of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. Avro schema always starts with one unnamed column, which can be a primitive type like string, or a complex type like record. We now map it to a column in BQ and fix the name to be "root". We'll consider striping the enclosing record at root level if this becomes a common request. But then we're processing the record type differently than other types.

The solution now is to strip the root record with a query and save to another table. Or, you can combine the load and strip in one step through federated tables:

bq query --external_table_definition=foo::AVRO=gs://your_bucket/path/file.avro* --destination_table your_dataset.your_table "SELECT root.* FROM foo"

Comment: I assumed that JSON and Avro have the same features and Avro could be used instead of JSON that is not a good format in terms of space consumption. This not the case (for now at least), instead Avro has this limitation that you cannot use arbitrary column names. In my case, our processing pipeline expects columns to have certain names, now I cannot achieve that because of the implicit `root_` prefix. IMHO it's a valid user requirement for an analytics database that end user can freely name the columns. Please support that feature in the future and please document the current feature.

Comment: so far, with root stuff - it is totally useless over-promoted feature and waste of time! is there plan to remove root record so user can totally control the schema??