# Remove root from avro upload to bigquery using nodejs

Tags: google-bigquery

Just starting out with bigquery and trying to find the best way to upload db tables to bq. We've been converting the table content to avro using the avsc library because from all the docs it seems that avro is the fastest way to load it but it adds a root element to the schema so that all the columns are root.name, root.time etc. I saw there was another [post about this from 2016 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862511/inserting-rows-with-multiple-columns-into-bigquery-using-avro) and the solution is to use a temporary table and strip out the root like this,
`bq query --external_table_definition=foo::AVRO=gs://your_bucket/path/file.avro* --destination_table your_dataset.your_table "SELECT root.* FROM foo"`
but the nodejs library only has instructions to accomplish permanent tables, not temporary ones. Even if I wanted to create a permanent table, I can't because due to the "root" it places all columns in one row and the amount of data exceeds the amount allowed in a single row. How can I load the data to bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external table using the bq js library [1] you need to set the options object appropriately [2]

[1] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/createTable.js

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916251/5873699